# Any full-blown framework for C?

Tags: .net, c, frameworks

I'm starting to learn the C language, and I'm used to having a lot of classes at my disposal in the .NET Framework. Is there any sort of framework like that for C? I'd prefer if it were cross-platform. Thanks.

Comment: framework for what ? GUI, networking, AI ?

Comment: There is nothing for C that comes anywhere near the massive scope of the .Net framework's class library. Typically, it's more a case of tracking down individual libraries for the bits and pieces you need and slapping them together by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [X11](http://www.x.org/wiki/)? It's a windowing system and the set of API combined. It's huge, by the way. And it's cross-platform.

Or, how about [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/)? It's a C-based GUI library, again cross-platform. And it's huge.

For non-GUI things, how about [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/austin/)? It's a set of common C functions, usable across wide range of operating systems (i.e. basically all.).

I can add more and more ...